# itertool group dynamic element in list python

Tags: python, list, group-by, python-itertools

I have a list of lists with multi columns:

```
column = [id, date,col1, col2...coln]
list_OfRows = [[1,date1, 10,20 ...23],
              [1,date1, 1,10 ...33],
              [2,date2, 3,7...8],
              [2,date2, 21,9...23],
              [2,date3, 10,56 ...20],
              [2,date4, 10,20 ...42]]
```

I want to group by on id and date and do sum on cols **WITHOUT USING PANDAS**

```
RESULT = [[1,date1, 11,30 ...56],
         [2,date2, 24,16...31],
         [2,date3, 10,20 ...20],
         [2,date4, 10,20 ...42]]
```

Comment: Please always provide a [mcve] and be sure to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What about `mapReduce` or simply use a dictionary where you collect the records by id and then apply the aggregation function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
from itertools import groupby


list_OfRows.sort(key=lambda x: x[:2])
res = []
for k, g in groupby(list_OfRows, key=lambda x: x[:2]):
    res.append(k + list(map(sum, zip(*[c[2:] for c in g]))))
```

which produces:

```
[[1, 'date1', 11, 30, 56], 
 [2, 'date2', 24, 16, 31], 
 [2, 'date3', 10, 56, 20], 
 [2, 'date4', 10, 20, 42]]
```

Comment: Perfect usage of groupby. Very elegant solution.

Comment: @Ma0 thanks !
i this error :
    

`res.append((k + list(map(sum, zip(*[c[2:] for c in g])))))
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`
some advice?

Comment: are these `numpy` arrrays?